# how do i turn off onCreated event listener in Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a simple chrome extension that automatically closes new tabs. The goal is for the extension to toggle on/off via clicking the browser icon. I'm able to activate it, however I'm unable to turn it off. Here's what I have so far:

```
var enable=false;
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
  enable = enable ? false : true;
  if(enable){
    chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function (tab) {
      chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);
    });
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: 'on.png'});
  }
  else{
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: 'icon.png'});
    // I'm not sure what to put here
  }
});
```

I have 2 different images to represent the on/off state which is working fine, however the listener remains active. I've tried removeListener to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a named function in order to use `removeListener`:

```
function myListener(tab){
    chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);
}

var enable=false;
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
  enable = !enable;
  if(enable){
    chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(myListener);
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: 'on.png'});
  }
  else{
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: 'icon.png'});
    chrome.tabs.onCreated.removeListener(myListener);
  }
});
```